# Running the GUI wallet connected to a daemon on my home network - How do I mark the daemon as 'trusted'?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, monero-wallet-rpc, remote-node

I'm using the GUI wallet on my windows desktop but run a daemon on a small linux home server. I can connect to my daemon by selecting 'remote node' in my settings using the local IP of my home server. The problem is I run into the error "Rescan spent can only be used with a trusted daemon" when rescanning my balance.
How do I tell the GUI that this daemon is trusted?

Comment: For the CLI, one can append the `--trusted-daemon` flag upon startup. I am not entirely sure this works for the GUI too though.